# How to get current date using cy.clock()

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can i get the date in format dd/mm/yyyy using cy.clock() and put the date in a textfield.. I have seen most examples are getting the timestamp but i dont need the time. Just need the current day date.

I do not want to use custom command here. Thank you

Comment: Cypress recommends using `day.js` to get the current date. [More information and an example can be found in their recipe.](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/blogs__dayjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `day.js` to get the current date and format it accordingly.

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

//In test
cy.log(dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY'))  //Prints todays date 30/09/2021
cy.get('textfield').type(dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY')) //input today's date in DD/MM/YYYY format
```

Answer (score 7):

The `cy.clock()` is about controlling the perceived date of the app.

From the [examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Now),

**Let the test run as at a certain date**

```js
const now = new Date(2017, 3, 14).getTime() // April 14, 2017 timestamp

cy.clock(now)
cy.visit('/index.html')
cy.get('#date').contains('2017-04-14')
```

**Typing into a field with a certain format**

If you want to `.type()` a particular date string, convert with `.toLocaleDateString()`

```js
const d = new Date()  // current date
// or
const d = new Date(2017, 3, 14)  // specific date

cy.get('input').type(d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))  // type in as 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

**Combining the two, e.g testing validation**

```js
// Set clock to a specific date
const now = new Date(2017, 3, 14).getTime() // April 14, 2017 timestamp
cy.clock(now)
cy.visit('/index.html')

// Type in an earlier date
const d = new Date(2017, 3, 13)
cy.get('input').type(d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))
  .blur()    // fire validation
  .should('contain', 'Error: Date entered must be a future date')
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled of this thread because I was searching for a way to retrieve the "current date" in the test. So, for other people who are searching for this: in another thread I found the answer:

```js
cy.window().then((win) => {
  const newDate = new Date(win.Date());
  // do something usefull with the date
}
```

Comment: thank you @Kleidersack This was lifesaver!!!!